# C# Selenium : How can I get css or Xpath when clicking on a button?

Tags: selenium, replay

I want to get the attributes of a button when clicking on it, when using a Chromedriver component, for instance : exactly what I get when I right-click -> Inspect with my browser (Chrome or Firefox).
How can I can get such info, if it's possible, in view to replay a web session, after such memorizing with Selenium.
At the moment, I can simulate a click on a button, knowing it's CSS-selector, for instance.
I just want to know if I can get the CSS-SElector, using Selenium, and clicking by hand (human action, so), avoiding a pre right-click -> Inspect with a classical browser.

```
            browser = new ChromeDriver();
            browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https:/twitter.com/EmiratesTeamNZ");
```

I want to get classname, or CSS-selector or Xpath of a like and retweet button being on the page, when I click on it.
This code, got here,don't work

```
browser.ExecuteAsyncScript("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.SomeTitle .bar'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')");
```

Any idea ?
Tx a lot for your help.

Comment: welcome to SO, please provide full context for your question, what have you tried and what error you getting, please read[MCVE]

Comment: I am abble to Selenium.click() on a button, knowing CSS-selector, 4 instance.

Comment: How you are clicking on the element? Which locator strategy you are using?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/

Comment: Yes, that seems to be exacly what I am looking for. Tx a lot for your help and the time you take to help me.